# After clicking on the checkbox when i use the keyboard navigation it should take to button

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am new to keyboard navigation, here is my angular application after clicking on that checkbox when i use the keyboard tab it should take to that button , right now i am using tabindex but it is not working.

```
 <div class="row well" ng-if="actionRequired">
     <label for="checkbox" class="bg-warning" style="background-color:#ddd;margin-left:32px;">
        <input type="checkbox"
               id="checkbox"
               ng-checked="false"
               ng-change="checkActions()"
               ng-model="action.complete"
               ng-disabled="contacts.length == 0" >
    {{checkListEmergencyConfirmLabel}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is the button code :

```
 <button type="button" role="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!reviewComplete()"
                ng-click="setReviewComplete()" tabindex="1">{{commitLabel}}</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `tabindex=1` for the `input type=checkbox` and `tabindex=2` for the `button`.
As MDN notes,

> The tabindex global attribute is an integer indicating if the element
>   can take input focus (is focusable), if it should participate to
>   sequential keyboard navigation

**Update**: You heard it wrong, see [W3C spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/editing.html#attr-tabindex)

> The tabindex content attribute allows authors to control whether an
>   element is supposed to be focusable, whether it is supposed to be
>   reachable using sequential focus navigation, and what is to be the
>   relative order of the element for the purposes of sequential focus
>   navigation. The name "tab index" comes from the common use of the
>   "tab" key to navigate through the focusable elements. The term
>   "tabbing" refers to moving forward through the focusable elements that
>   can be reached using sequential focus navigation.
>
> The tabindex attribute, if specified, must have a value that is a
>   valid integer.

Comment: but giving like that using the tab i am not able to go to check box in the form , and i heard it is not good approach to use tabindex >1

Comment: > 1 is a valid integer